# Specify versionCode in android/gradle projects project root build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently switched from Eclipse to Android Studio (for test purposes) with an production project and it feel really great. I like the gradle way very much.

In Android Studio the project structure looks (simplified) something like this

```
+RandomProject
|-+Random
| |- build.gradle (lets call it build2)
| |- [...]
|- build.gradle (lets call it build1)
|- [..]
```

The **build1** file has the following content by default:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

I wonder if its possible/a good practice to specify the versionName and versionCode in that (**build1**) file, so that it is going to be "inherited" to the **build2** file. (and if so, how?)

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with [ExtraPropertiesExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

`RandomProject\build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext.compileSdkVersion=19
ext.buildToolsVersion="19"
ext.versionName="1.0.7"
ext.versionCode=7
```

`RandomProject\Random\build.gradle`

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        versionName rootProject.versionName
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to install it first? as it gives me an error Could not find property 'RandomProject' on ProductFlavorDsl_Decorated...

Comment: Is it re-sync project issue? Try to press `Sync project with gradle files` button or restart idea.

Comment: I do it by ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build on the console - Gradle Version 1.8

Comment: You put `rootProject.versionName`, not `RandomProject.versionName`, correct? If its possible could you add to your question `RandomProject\build.gradle`, `RandomProject\settings.gradle`, `RandomProject\Random\build.gradle` files.

Comment: Sorry mate I am to stupid to copy paste ...I did the RandomProject.* mistake. Thanks for your help! - do you think this is good practice to store it there?

Comment: What about minSdk and targetSdk?  Can those be specified in ext.

Comment: Any variable can be set there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rootProject.ext.versionName`??

Answer (score 8):

The [New Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips) site now has a tip about this. It's similar to Sergii's answer, but subtly different:

In the root project's build.gradle:

```
ext {
  compileSdkVersion = 19
  buildToolsVersion = "19.0.1"
}
```

in all the android modules:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
}
```

Comment: What is the between of "rootProject.compileSdkVersion" and "rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion"?

Comment: rootProject is not writeable, but rootProject.ext is.